# 2D sprite leaving after images in the blank area while moving cameras

Tags: unity

I am using unity to create a top down 2d game, right now I have not added constraint to cameras, so when my cam moves into blank area, there will be some repeated images every frame. Here is a screenshot, anyone has any idea how to solve it?[image: repeated sprite image]

[image: cam setting 1]

[image: cam setting 2]

[image: lighting rendering and skybox setting]

Comment: resolve what? adding constrain to the camera? fixing repeated images?

Comment: Can you show us the configuration of your Camera component, particularly the clearing settings?

Comment: @DMGregory Hi, I am using URP, so the clear settings is the background type right? I changed it to solid color, and the repeated images are not showing now, my default clearing setting is skybox. I tried to create a test project with default background type skybox, and there is no problem with my test project, any idea why this is happening in my own project with the same camera settings?

Comment: Try showing us your skybox settings.

Comment: @DMGregory I just added two images of my cam settings, the first one is my current project, and the second one is a test project I created, they are just the same, but my own project has a black background, and the test project is blue.

Comment: Yes, and I asked you for your skybox settings. Don't forget to caption your images when editing your question, so that other readers don't need to refer to the comments to understand the main post.

Comment: @DMGregory Hi, I just added the skybox setting and the rendering lighting setting, I guess I should let the skybox material be empty, unity somehow sets the default URP 3D skybox to my project.